# Gradle ssh plugin: works for T-mobile, not working for Google-Fi

Tags: gradle, ssh, connection, gradle-ssh-plugin

Gradle ssh plugin: works for T-mobile, not working for Google-Fi.

With google FI, WinSCP can connect to linux server without problem, and PuTTY works too. But gradle ssh plugin could not connect to server using the same key. T-mobile works fine for gradle ssh plugin.

```
remotes {
    server1 {
        host = 'mycompany.com'
        port = 22
        user = 'user1'
        identity = new File('c:/key1.pem')
    }
}

ssh.run {
    session(remotes.server1) {
        get from: "/path/foo", into: 'c:/temp/'
    }
}
```

Error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Why google FI not working?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly IPv6 vs IPv4 issue. The hostname might have both addresses and Gradle might pick different one than the PuTTY/WinSCP.

Try using either IP address instead of the hostname.